# drop a key from dictionary by value

Tags: python, dictionary

How drop items with None or empty values from a given dictionary?

```
dict_ = {"a": "A", "b": "B", "c": None, "d": " "}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to define what you mean by "empty value". In your example, `"d"` is not empty, it contains whitespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in one line using dictionary comprehension:

```
dict_ = {"a": "A", "b": "B", "c": None, "d": " "}
dict_ = {k:v for k,v in dict_.items() if v and v != ' '}
```

and the result will be:

```
Out[4]: {'a': 'A', 'b': 'B'}
```

Comment: What about values with more than only two spaces and with a `0`?